# android buttons did not change backgroud

Tags: java, android, xml

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="200sp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makepro"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here I try to remove the Linear Layout to see if it works but not working.

buttonshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="14dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:centerColor="#47A891"
        android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="270dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#878787"
        />
</shape>
```

Button did not change background and I can't find the mistake. Can you help me?
I try to find something similar to my problem, with not helpful result.

Comment: Are you using material components library? which version?

Answer (score 0):

```
 I use Textview instead of Button then Background Image is display. You can also use ImageButton instead of 
 button . try below code . it is working.  
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/makepro"
 android:text="Button"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
 android:textSize="30sp"
 android:layout_width="270dp"
 android:layout_height="60dp"
 android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
 android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
 android:shadowDx="0"
 android:shadowDy="0"
 android:shadowRadius="5"/>
```

Comment: I check it but it doesnt work like a button, actually my emulator doesn't run.

Comment: try to use ImageButton instead of button.

Comment: I try it but how can i put text inside ImiageButton

Comment: you can not put text in imageButton .  put TextView above imageview  to display text

Comment: Ok... thank you a lot!!